# Reading text from file and comparing it to seriers of characters

Tags: java, string, file, text, compare

can I get recommendation or like an advice for what should be used or be known to complete this task (in the most rudimentary way I guess). if someone would be willing to write a code that would be fantastic but vague answers on the neccesary knowledge or technique will suffice.

I would like a program where at the start you input characters either seperataed by pressing enter or a string that could be like chopped up into separate items of an array (I guess) - characters separated by a comma - and that would be then compared to a txt file that contains series of entries and only those that contain some of (meaning shorter) or all of the characters that have been provided at the start would be printed, perhaps even the print would be separated by a length of the entry (word).

Any ideas on how to do this? Also, can the results be printed somewhere else than the command line, like another txt file? Need to do this in java. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, by programming it in Java. SO is not an advice forum.

Comment: ok so is this wrong section of forum or wrong site for this kind of question alltogether? if thats the case, do you know any like good source of information (or advice forums) for this, i have no idea how to read txt file for example, and ok, Ill try to figure out the rest even tou it'll be all clunky.

Comment: Start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following example:

```
public class SimpleExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Scanner inputNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> listOfNumbersToStore = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> listOfNumbersToCheck = new ArrayList<>();
        int number;
        String answer;
        boolean flag = true;
        // do code within a loop while flag is true
        do {
            // print message to screen
            System.out.print("Would you like to put new number to your file list (Y/N): ");
            // get answer (Y/N) to continue
            answer = inputNumbers.next();
            // if answer is Y or y
            if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                // print message
                System.out.print("Put your number: ");
                // get input integer and assign it to number
                number = inputNumbers.nextInt();
                // add that number to a list of numbers to store to file
                listOfNumbersToStore.add(number);
            } else if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                flag = false;
            }

        } while (flag);
        writeToFile(listOfNumbersToStore);
        System.out.println("---------- Check numbers ----------");
        flag = true; // set it again to true
        //do code within a loop while flag is true
        do {
            System.out.print("Would you like to put new number to your check list (Y/N) : ");
            answer = inputNumbers.next();
            if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                System.out.print("Put your number: ");
                number = inputNumbers.nextInt();
                listOfNumbersToCheck.add(number);
            } else if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                flag = false;
            }

        } while (flag);
        // get a list from a file
        List<Integer> readFromFile = readFromFile();
        // check if there are any common elements within compared lists
        boolean areThereAnyCommonElements = !Collections.disjoint(
                listOfNumbersToCheck, readFromFile);

        //create a new treeset used for containing unique elements and ordering it naturally, from 0 to n
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(listOfNumbersToCheck);
        set.retainAll(readFromFile);
        // print these messages
        System.out.println("Are there any common integers between a list from a file and checking list? " + areThereAnyCommonElements);
        System.out.println("Those integers are: " + set.toString());
    }

    /**
     * List implements Seriazable interface, therefore store it to a file
     * serialized
     *
     * @param numberOfIntegers
     */
    public static void writeToFile(List<Integer> numberOfIntegers) {
        try {
            // create a file output stream to write to the file with the specified name. 
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("tekstDataOutputStream");
            // writes the serialization stream header to the underlying file stream; 
            ObjectOutputStream dataOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream));
            // write a list to object output stream
            dataOutputStream.writeObject(numberOfIntegers);
            //close them
            dataOutputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioE) {
            System.err.println("JVM reported an error! Take a look: " + ioE);
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> readFromFile() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        //create an empty list of integers
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //opening a connection to an actual file
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tekstDataOutputStream");
            //used for reading from a specified input stream
            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            //get that list 
            result = (List<Integer>) reader.readObject();
            //close streams
            reader.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (IOException ioE) {
            System.err.println("JVM reported an error! Take a look: " + ioE);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks. I'll be looking into this, so far I don't know half the things in here.